# How to configure WebStorm FileWatchers to use babel and retain source directory structure

Tags: build, webstorm

I'd like to use WebStorm's File Watchers and macros to transpile ES2015 JavaScript to ES5 JavaScript, and replicate the source directory structure into the target directory.  I cannot find a combination of macro variables or other configuration to permit this.  My project is organized like this:

```
~/ProjectName/src/app.html
~/ProjectName/src/es2015/app.js
~/ProjectName/src/es2015/services/webapi.js
~/ProjectName/src/es5/app.js
~/ProjectName/src/es5/services/webapi.js
```

Jetbrain's documentation recommends using `$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$;` however, I believe this assumes your source in the project root itself and not a `src` subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

**Arguments**:

```
--source-maps --presets es2015 --out-file $ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js $FilePath$
```

or

```
--source-maps --presets es2015 --out-file $ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirPathFromParent(src)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js $FilePath$
```

**Output paths to refresh**:

```
$ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map
```

or

```
$ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirPathFromParent(src)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirPathFromParent(src)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map
```

Comment: This solution works like a charm, it must be selected as correct answer!